# Angular 2 ngIf and ngFor combination

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am wondering if I have a combination of `ngIf` and `ngFor` like this. What will run first when Angular creates its elements?

`<li *ngIf='isDisplayed' *ngFor='let item of itemsList'></li>`

Imaging in a scenario that we have an `itemsList` of couple of thousands `item`, and `ngFor` runs first would make application a complete disaster. Of course I can use a `div` to wrap this and put `ngIf` there, but knowing more about this is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported to add more than one structural directive on one element. <strike>You need to use the canonical form using an explicit `<template>` tag for at least one of them</strike>.
Use an extra `<ng-container *ngIf="..."></ng-container>` or `<ng-container *ngFor="...">` element for one of both structural direcives.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4205

Comment: What do you mean by "not supported"? I mean, technically I can use them and it's still running, right?

Comment: See the linked issue. In the next version this will throw. You need to move one (`*ngFor` or `*ngIf`) to a `<template>` tag. The answer to the question I marked this a dup of, shows how to do it.